# How to add domain to Firebase and subdomain to GCP in Cloudflare

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, subdomain, cloudflare

I have the `example.com` domain in **Cloudflare** connected to an application hosted in **Firebase** and a second application that should use the subdomain`api.example.com` hosted in GAE, but when I try to connect the subdomain in **GAE** I got the following error:

The CAA domain registration does not allow you to activate the certificate. Composed of DNS settings.

The domain works perfectly with Firebase, but the subdomain does not work with GAE. I have added the corresponding records in each case, but the subdomain still doesn't work, which only shows me this screen:

[Cloudflare screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLEFn.png)

My question is if I have a domain on one platform and a subdomain on another. Well, I actually know that this can be done, because once I set up the subdomain in Heroku and domain in Firebase, but I have not managed to do it with GAE and Firebase

Comment: A first thing to try would be to disable the Cloudflare CDN/proxy layer (if the UI is still the same as it used to be, turn off the orange cloud next to the subdomain and make it gray). That will pass traffic directly to GAE and may work better.

Comment: Do you mean activate the option "DNS only"?


When entering api.example.com, I have the following answer:
```This website cannot be accessed
api.example.com closed the connection unexpectedly.```

Comment: I think so, yes. I'm not sure where to point you next as it depends largely on your specific DNS records and GAE configuration.

Comment: You forget, this solution works for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Following are the access the required setup.

***Settings:***

```
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|
|    Type    |       Name      |     Content     |     TTL    |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|
|     A      | api.example.com |      HostIP     |     Auto   |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|
|   CNAME    |       www       | api.example.com |    Auto    |
|------------|-----------------|-----------------|------------|
```